# One to One ER with a Type or Status table instead of a Type or Status column

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

I have a long way to go with ER modelling, as you'll soon see, but I have a project I'm doing for a construction firm and I'm getting my hands wet with the database model.

The company is a roof inspections company and they have projects on sites and proposals for potential projects on sites.

A project is either a consultation, an inspection or a report (Type).
The project is either Complete, In progress or at a stage they call RFF(Ready for final) (State).

The proposal can have the same TYPE as the projects but has its own STATUS states.

A project also consists of many trips that have their own set of STATUS'.

So I have the current model looking something like this:

[Simplified Er Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVB1W.png)

Is this a good approach? Or is it better to have a separate table for each entity like:   Project_Status and Project_Type etc....?

Or even just a column in the Project as a string, and limit the input in the application to one of the 3 types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the separated entity approach, and I use it in my work.
This way I have more flexibility over the values for TYPE and STATUS.
From a software developer point of view I will rather use them:

1. When I will need to use this values in future developments such as: form   components  like combo boxes and drop downs list that rely on id and value.
2. When more values should be added to types and statuses I will just add them to the tables using a simple insert query rather than change the code.

Comment: Ok, even though several entities will now have duplicate data?  For example Project_Type and Profile_Type will essentially be identical? 

It makes sense I suppose with Project_Status and Profile_Status as they would look different having different statuses but only a little bit.  I find this a tricky concept to get right

Comment: Think of a form in your system when you fill in or updating a project.
You will probably have a drop down list to choose a type for proposal, and a type for project. This drop down list is using the type table for a repository. If you have one type table  serving proposal and project then the user to choose between all types, and he could choose a type that is not suitable for project or proposal. If you realy want one table add a field to type table that contains values like project or proposal, but this is not a good idea for the long run. Use 2 table even thought they are almost identical